# Installing/Using Bower on Uberspace with NPM

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install, uberspace

Hi I use uberspace and installed ghost there. Ghost uses npm.

If I try:

```
npm install -g bower
```

It doesn't install it and throws a lot of erros messages what makes sense because the server is shared between many users.
    sudo npm install -g bower
Tells me that it doesn't know bower

If I install it locally with

```
npm install bower
```

It installs it to ../node_modules. But using for example

```
bower install angular-mailchimp
```

Throws the error:
-bash: bower: command not found

How do I get it running?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get Bower installed in the correct place by prefixing the global install with the following command.

```
npm install -g --prefix=$HOME bower
```

Comment: Ok thx yes it is solved. I do after 2 days atm it is not possible.